# Add pkgdown html to site articles generated by rmarkdown::render()

Tags: r, r-markdown, pkgdown

I'm hoping to use [pkgdown](https://pkgdown.r-lib.org/) to generate analysis websites and would like to use a large object in multiple site articles without either re-computing or saving a `.Rda` file to include with the package build (i.e., `data/x.Rda`).

By default, `pkgdown::build_site()` ignores files in the `vignettes` subdirectory with preceding underscores. My current approach uses a file `vignettes/articles.Rmd` to perform some calculations that generate a large object, then renders additional `.html` files using this global object via calls to `rmarkdown::render()`. The contents of the `.Rmd` look something like this:

````
---
title: "Render Articles"
---

Would like to be able to share `x` with reports and maintain pkgdown html.

```{r}
x <- runif(n = 10000000) # Some calculations that generate a large object
```

Global object `x` is available from `_QC1.Rmd`

```{r}
# Code chunk to generate report (repeated for multiple _*.Rmd files)
rmarkdown::render(
  input = "_QC1.Rmd",  # pkgdown::build_site() ignores files with preceding underscore
  output_file = "QC1.html"  # renders HTML file output without "_"; copied to docs/articles/
)
```
````

The `_pkgdown.yml` can be modified to pickup the html files rendered from the Rmarkdown reports, but they lose the site formatting that is automated for other `.Rmd` files by `pkgdown::build_site()`.

**I'd like to include the pkgdown site html formatting (i.e., title and site navbar) in these Rmarkdown reports if possible.**

`_pkgdown.yml` contents:

```
navbar:
  title: ~
  left:
    - text: QC
      menu:
        - text: QC1
          href: articles/QC1.html
        - text: QC2
          href: articles/QC2.html
```

I'm unsure if there is a better way for sharing an object across articles (though I understand these are typically self-contained). This approach works, but the html pages rendered for the Rmarkdown reports lose pkgdown formatting which drops the site navbar.

```
# Example of package vignettes subdirectory contents
1 vignettes
2  ¦--_QC1.Rmd  # ignored by pkgdown::build_site()
3  ¦--_QC2.Rmd
4  ¦--articles.html 
5  ¦--articles.Rmd  # contains R chunks for rendering Rmarkdown reports
6  ¦--QC1.html  # picked up in _pkgdown.yml from `docs/articles/`
7  °--QC2.html
```

Edit: Will look into the source code here:

https://github.com/r-lib/pkgdown/blob/master/R/build-articles.R